# Can't run Java EE project through WildFly 10

Tags: java, netbeans, server, wildfly

When I unzip the `wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip` file on my computer at home. Then WildFly starts running automatically. I had verified this through going to `localhost:8080`. Because of this I can't run my Java EE project on Netbeans (I have added WildFly as server in Netbeans). In the logs I see:

`Address localhost: 8080 is already in use`

I also can't shutdown WildFly through the following command:

`$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown`

However I can shutdown WildFly by killing his process. But this still doesn't fixed my issue on Netbeans. Because I still get to see: `Address localhost: 8080 is already in use`.

At my work when I had unzipped the `wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip` file. It didn't start automatically I also had no problems with running my project on WildFly. And I also can shutdown WildFly through the command line or Netbeans.

Anyone that maybe knows how I can fix my WildFly server problem on my computer at home?

Comment: Wouldnt NetBeans start the wildfly on its own? In IntelliJ it is like that. No need to start the server yourself.

Comment: @cgew85 No it didn't came with Netbeans. Netbeans does come with GlassFish, but I don't know if it isn't a problem if I use WildFly at work and GlassFish at my home.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NetBeans are you using ? Until 8.2 WildFly 10 isn't correctly identified.
You may try NetBeans 8.2 RC1 from https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/ or a nightly build as this would fix your issue.

NetBeans checks if there the instance is already running before trying to start it, so you don't have to start it beforehand but you can :)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1